# Objects and comparing in Javascript, how to pass the value into the method

Tags: javascript

I got this Javascript exercise.
I couldn't figure out how to pass the value of the pay of each person into the "comparePay" method. I'd be glad if you help me this.

Thank you in advance.

---

Create 3 Person objects, with the attributes "name", "occupation" and "pay", as well as the method "comparePay(person)", which compares the pay values of the object calling it and the object passed to it as argument, then printing the result:

```yaml
[name of object calling the method] earns [difference] more than [other's name]
[name of object calling the method] earns [difference] less than [other's name]
[name of object calling the method] earns as much as [name]
```

The objects should have the following values:

```yaml
Michael, JS-programmer, 5000
Lena, Python-programmer, 1500
Brad, Teacher, 800
```

The output should be like this.↓

```yaml
First person's name: Michael
Second person's job: Python-programmer
Third person's pay: 800
    
Michael earns 3500 more than Lena
Brad earns 700 less than Lena
Brad earns as much as Brad
```

Here is what I have done so far.

```js
 function Person(name, occupation, pay) {
      this.name = name;
      this.occupation = occupation;
      this.pay = pay;
    　this.comparePay = function(person) { /* compare the value of the pay */
         var difference = person.pay - person.pay;
         if (difference > 0) {
             return person.name + " earns " + difference + " more than " + person.name;
         } else if (difference === 0) {
             return person.name + " earns as much as " + person.name;
         } else {
             return person.name + " earns " + Math.abs(difference) + " less than " + person.name;
         } 
        };
    　}

    person1 = new Person("Michael", "JS-programmer", 5000);
    person2 = new Person("Lena", "Python-programmer", 1500);
    person3 = new Person("Brad", "Teacher", 800);
```

and here is the prepared code, so they are not allowed to be edited.

```
console.log("First person's name: " + person1.name);
console.log("Second person's job: " + person2.occupation);
console.log("Third person's pay: " + person3.pay + "\n");

person1.comparePay(person2);
person3.comparePay(person2);
person3.comparePay(person3);
```

Comment: `person.pay - person.pay` is obviously always `0` since you are subtracting a value from itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `this.comparePay` function you should use `this` to access the object properties:

`this.pay`, `this.name`, etc.

```js
this.comparePay = function(person) { 
  var difference = this.pay - person.pay;
  ...
}
```

```js
function Person(name, occupation, pay) {
      this.name = name;
      this.occupation = occupation;
      this.pay = pay;
    　this.comparePay = function(person) { /* compare the value of the pay */
         var difference = this.pay - person.pay;
         if (difference > 0) {
             return this.name + " earns " + difference + " more than " + person.name;
         } 
         if (difference === 0) {
             return this.name + " earns as much as " + person.name;
         } 
         return this.name + " earns " + Math.abs(difference) + " less than " + person.name;
        };
    　}

person1 = new Person("Michael", "JS-programmer", 5000);
person2 = new Person("Lena", "Python-programmer", 1500);
person3 = new Person("Brad", "Teacher", 800);

console.log(person1.name);
console.log(person1.pay);
console.log(person2.name);
console.log(person2.pay);
console.log(person3.name);
console.log(person3.pay);

console.log( person1.comparePay(person2) );
console.log( person3.comparePay(person2) );
console.log( person2.comparePay(person1) );
console.log( person3.comparePay(person3) );
```

---

Tips: You can also remove the `else/if` statements since you are returning inside the `if` statements. `Paulic-crtn`'s advice is also important, so try to stick to `let/const` when declaring variables in JS.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes from your comparaison (you're comparing the same object attributes). You want to compare the object passed in the function's argument with the current object.

So I guess you can try to replace

```js
var difference = person.pay - person.pay;
```

with:

```js
const difference = this.pay - person.pay;
```

Same for

```js
return person.name + " earns " + difference + " more than " + person.name;
```

should be

```js
return this.name + " earns " + difference + " more than " + person.name;
```

Otherwise it will return the same names. You can also use template literals notation

```js
return `${this.name} earns ${difference} more than ${person.name}`;
```

Hope it makes sense. Also don't forget to use `let` or `const` instead of `var` :)